# Convert JSON nested array to Python nested list in one-liner

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I would like to convert JSON nested array to Python nested list with one-liner Python method.

Below is the sample of my JSON nested array:

```
my_dict = {
    "background": "This is a test text.",
    "person": [
        {"name": "Max", "tranx_info": [
            {"tranx_date":"7/1/2020","amount": 82 },
            {"tranx_date":"27/2/2017","amount":177 }]
        },
        {"name": "Lily", "tranx_info": [
            {"tranx_date":"12/7/1989","amount": 165 },
            {"tranx_date":"28/2/1998","amount": 200 },
            {"tranx_date":"28/2/2098","amount": 34 }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I assume this will be nested list comprehension in Python? What I had tried so far but I'm only able to make the result into a list:

```
tranx_date_result = [x["tranx_date"] for y in my_dict["person"] for x in y["tranx_info"]]

#output
>>> ["7/1/2020","27/2/2017","12/7/1989","28/2/1998","28/2/2098"]
```

I would my `"tranx_date"` result to be in a nested list; something like this:

```
tranx_date_result = [["7/1/2020","27/2/2017"],["12/7/1989","28/2/1998","28/2/2098"]]
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use nested list comprehensions:

```
>>> [[x["tranx_date"] for x in y["tranx_info"]] for y in my_dict["person"]]
[['7/1/2020', '27/2/2017'], ['12/7/1989', '28/2/1998', '28/2/2098']]
```